# OpenNi Skeleton Tracking - Save calibration data

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, nite

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i use the openNi skeleton tracking. I achieved good results by saving the calibration data of the first Person, and the loading the data for all other Persons. Is it possible to save/load the data to/from a file or something like that? I found nothing like that in the API...

cheers,
Thorsten

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9466/openni-skeleton-tracking---save-calibration-data/) by [Thorsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/306/thorsten/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2011-03-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can use [Bags](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Bags) if you want to store ROS messages, if thats what you want. If its just some bunch of params then you could just write your own file for saving and loading.

---

Originally posted by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) with karma: 284 on 2011-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-09-11**:
Bags are the solution in ROS, for OpenNI native solution I suggest you ask this on their forums.

**Comment by [Thorsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/306/thorsten/) on 2011-03-17**:
I know about bags, but that's not the solution... The Problem is in the OpenNi API...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently realised that new methods have been added to the OpenNI API to allow saving/loading skeleton calibration data to a file. However, I've trying to make them work without success. The methods I'm talking about are

```
XnStatus xn::SkeletonCapability::SaveCalibrationDataToFile(XnUserID user, const XnChar * strFileName)
XnStatus xn::SkeletonCapability::LoadCalibrationDataFromFile(XnUserID user, const XnChar * strFileName)
```

Has anyone managed to use those successfully?

**Update:** The code I used to test this is a modified version of openni_tracker.cpp in trunk. You can check lines 201 to 268 in http://pastebin.com/d0m6J6tb

The service requests contain the user id (int) and a filename (string), and I've tried both absolute and relative paths for the filename without success.

**Update 2:** Apparently it is a OpenNI version issue: http://answers.ros.org/question/1631/openni-save-calibration-to-file-failed-this

---

Originally posted by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) with karma: 1071 on 2011-07-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-08-08**:
I have installed the latest unstable version of OpenNI, but running the Sample-NiUserTracker does not save the calibration. Which programs do I need to run to save the data? Also, what type of file do I need when using the SaveCalibrationToFile function?

**Comment by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) on 2011-08-07**:
Apparently it is a OpenNI version issue: http://answers.ros.org/question/1631/openni-save-calibration-to-file-failed-this

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-08-05**:
Also, why is it set up to advertise the save and load functions? Shouldn't they just be performed by openni_tracker.cpp?

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-08-05**:
Where can I find more information on calibration_save_load? The parameters for the save and load functions come from it, but I don't see any constructions for these parameters.

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-08-05**:
I am going to experiment with this, and if I get something that works, I will post it.

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-08-05**:
Thanks, that worked. After trying out the code, It seemed to act exactly like the original openni_tracker.cpp. I think that it might be better for the CalibrationEnd function to call the save functions, and for the NewUser function to call the load functions, as opposed to main calling these.

**Comment by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) on 2011-08-04**:
You probably need write permissions on the whole folder. Do a chmod -R a+rw to be safe ;)

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-08-04**:
I removed the ROS_NOBUILD file, but I still have to use sudo to change any files. Also, when I try to rosmake the package, an error appears when it tries to create the binary file.

**Comment by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) on 2011-08-04**:
You can make a copy of the package and prepend its path to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. The ROS tools (rosmake, rosrun, etc.) will use the copy of the package found first (leftmost) on ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. If you copy a package installed with apt, you'll need to fix permissions and remove the ROS_NOBUILD file.

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-08-04**:
I want to try this out, but I want to leave a copy of the original openni_tracker package. What is the best way to do this? I think that simply using the "cp" command would cause problems.

**Comment by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) on 2011-08-03**:
Don't worry, it was a legitimate question. The way I tried those was by adding a couple of load/save services to openni_tracker. Unfortunately the files are on my laptop at work, so I'll be unable to show them until tomorrow (maybe late evening for you).

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-08-03**:
Sorry, that was pretty dumb of me. Are you using these with the ROS code at all? If so, could you show me how you altered the code?

**Comment by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) on 2011-08-02**:
No, @qdocehf, I'm not ;)

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-08-02**:
Are you just copying the functions from the OpenNI API and pasting them into the ROS code?

**Comment by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) on 2011-07-28**:
I'm guessing that it might be related to the OpenNI version in the Ubuntu openni-dev package. I'm afraid to test installing a newer version by hand on the production machine. When can a new version of OpenNI and NITE be expected to be released as an Ubuntu package?

**Comment by [JoeRomano](https://answers.ros.org/users/34/joeromano/) on 2011-07-19**:
they do not work for me either. I didn't try and debug too much. I'd be interested if there is a fix.